# Don't repeat method un a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, controller

I have  a controller for my admin that looks

```rb
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
   ...
  private

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:sort_direction]) ? params[:sort_direction] : 'asc'
  end
end
```

And I have other controllers that inherit this controller. What I want is the method `sort_field` to be available without adding to each new controller

```rb
class Admin::BooksController < Admin::AdminController
  LIMIT = 40
  SORT_FIELD = "name"
  SORT_DIR = "asc"
  SORT_FIELDS = %w(id title author publication_date created_at).freeze

  # GET /admin/books
  def index
    _books = Book.limit(LIMIT).order(sort_field => sort_direction)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        render(inertia: 'Admin/Books/Index', props: {})
      }
    end
  end

  private
  # I would like to have in my Admin::AdminController so I don't repeat for each controller
  # The method should be aware of the constants defined
  def sort_field
    SORT_FIELDS.include?(params[:sort_field]) ? params[:sort_field] : SORT_FIELD
  end
end
```

Comment: How would a superclass know about constants in child classes *(in a reasonable way)*? You could provide accessors for values provided by subclasses; there may be even cleaner options though. I probably wouldn't go down the metaprogramming road for this, at least not with the context provided in the question.

Comment: I been thinking that I could avoid the use of constants and just provide the methods sort_fields and sort_field, but it would be nice to know a way for this.